# Why can't xfs_freeze find this directory when called with ec2-consistent-snapshot?

Tags: amazon-ec2, xfs

**On my management server:**

```
/usr/bin/ec2-consistent-snapshot --freeze-filesystem /mnt/websites --description "FOO-DATA $(date)" vol-d84bhi64 --region eu-west-1
/mnt/websites: No such file or directory
ec2-consistent-snapshot: ERROR: xfs_freeze -f /mnt/websites: failed(256)
```

**On the server that the volume in question is attached to:**

```
[root@foo ec2-user]# df -TH
Filesystem    Type     Size   Used  Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1    ext4     8.5G   1.2G   7.2G  15% /
tmpfs        tmpfs     880M    50k   880M   1% /dev/shm
/dev/xvdf      xfs      54G   321M    54G   1% /mnt

[root@foo ec2-user]# ls -al /mnt
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  4 root           root     45 Sep  8 12:36 .
dr-xr-xr-x 22 root           root   4096 Sep 13 15:07 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 mysql          mysql    16 Sep  8 12:36 mysql
-rw-r--r--  1 root           root      0 Sep  8 12:11 stuff
drwsrwsr-x  5 someuser       apache   37 Sep 21 15:41 websites
```

**Running xfs_freeze on the machine works:**

```
[root@fb ec2-user]# xfs_freeze -f /mnt/websites
[root@fb ec2-user]# xfs_freeze -u /mnt/websites
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the `--freeze-filesystem` (or `--xfs-filesystem`) option, then the `ec2-consistent-snapshot` program must be run on the instance where the file system is mounted.  Otherwise, it can't run xfs_freeze against that filesystem.

I am the author/maintainer of `ec2-consistent-snapshot`.  I'll look at making this requirement clearer in the documentation.

There was a submitted patch that went a ways towards making `ec2-consistent-snapshot` work on remote systems (with `ssh` to run commands like `xfs_freeze`).  This would help reduce the existing requirement to have the AWS credentials on the instance.  I forget why the patch did not get incorporated, but will take another look at it.

If you're trying to avoid having AWS credentials on the instance, here's an article I wrote to limit your risk:

> Improving Security on EC2 With AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)
>   http://alestic.com/2010/09/aws-iam

Comment: Oh, ok. That is not clear. I found the same thing with the --mysql flag. It seems that I needed to set up remote mysql access to the instance I was snapshotting on in order to connect and issue the mysql flush/lock commands. I discovered that through informative error messages, but the error messages for the freeze are not so clear. So...basically, to use this the instance has to snapshot itself. Is that correct?

Comment: jdw: You got it.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. That's gonna take some re-jigging of my methodology.